# Redirect to currentpage and append querystring after form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, umbraco

From my surfacecontroller I wish to append the current querystring to the redirect action. I cant seem to find any appropriate method of doing this.

The page the form gets sent from contains a tab that is shown by appending the querystring to the url. The form is submitted from this tab, and I want the thank you message to be displayed on the same tab.

The querystring is #inquery

From my surfacecontroller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HandleFormSubmit(InquiryFormModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return CurrentUmbracoPage();
    }

    // Mail date goes here...

    TempData["success"] = true;

    return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

As you have properly guessed, I want #inquery appended to the URL returned by the RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage() method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you return the current page, add in a viewbag object with the querystring contained within. Have this field stored in a hidden input in your HTML and have your clientside javascript test for it and append it to the URL if it exists.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ViewBag.URLString = "stringhere"
    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

then in your HTML.

```
<input id="URLString" type="hidden" />
```

And in your javascript (if you're using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.location.href += $("#URLString").val();
});
```

I haven't fully qualified this code so it won't work as it is, but it's there more to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the time to take a look at it now, but I will return to the subject asap! And thanks for the code snippets! Btw, can I also add a ViewBag when redirecting on a valid ModelState?

Comment: I think so. But, if you can't then another option is to use the ASP.NET Session object and either access that in your client side code using Razor or whatever else you are using in your client side mark up, or you can access the Session variable using an AJAX call. Just to cover a few more options for you.

Comment: I wonder if there would be a solution to this using only server-side logic and no javascript?